# Calculate percentage difference for two sets of points

Tags: quantiles

As the title says, I'd like to calculate the percentage difference for two sets of points. For example, suppose I have $S_{1}=\{(1,x_{1}),(2,x_{2}),(3,x_{3})\}$ and $S_{2}=\{(1,y_{1}),(2,y_{2}),(3,y_{3})\}$. How can I know the difference in percentage between both sets of data. What is the correct way to do that? Is that kind of assessment meaningful to establish to which degree of precision a set of data is preferred over the other?

In my particular case, $S_{1}$ is simply a set of numerical results obtained by [DSMC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_simulation_Monte_Carlo) and $S_{2}$ was obtained by a theoretical result. I'd like to quantify how much difference exist between each other in order to establish when it is convenient to use one or the other.

By "difference in percentage" I mean [percent difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent_difference). Hopefully that clarifies a bit the question.

**UPDATE:**

Another way to formulate my question would be: How can I arrive to conclusions such as "The results from experiment A are inaccurate by 10% with respect to experiment B", when experiment A and B are a set of values.

Comment: To keep the responses relevant to the question you have in mind, could you say a little more about what these data are, what you mean by "difference in percentage," and why that's important to you?

Comment: Alright. I will edit the post.

Comment: It's still not clear what you mean. Do you mean the number of points which are different? Do you mean the percent difference in the averages? Do you mean the mean percent difference for each of the pairs of points? There's no obvious way to interpret what you're asking for. Percentage difference is not something people normally think about for sets of points. Percent difference can fully specify how two individual points are different, but you need a lot more information to fully specify how different two sets of points are.

Comment: @John: Exactly, percentage difference works fine for a pair of points, but when someone says that certain result (as a function or as a set of numbers) is inaccurate by 10% or 15% with respect to another result, how can you arrive to such conclusion?

Comment: By the way, I don't mean any particular question as "How to calculate percent difference". I want to know what is the correct way to reach the kind of conclusion I mentioned before.

Comment: Let me give you an example, say you have 1 population of 50 individuals and 2 bathroom scales. You want to know if both bathroom scales work equally well? Or if one scale with give readings higher or lower than the other?

Comment: @carlosdc: No, sorry. Did you read the update?. I put an example there of what I want to know.

Comment: @Robert Smith, Yeah, sorry what you said doesn't make much sense. I'm trying to put it in statistical terms.

Comment: @carlosdc: See the answer posted by Dennis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's compare two lists of numbers — are they from the same distribution ?
For example, how close are the lists of 20 numbers, "|" marks,

```
||||||.||.||...||.....||.|................|.....................................
|||.|...|..|...|.......||...|...|...|.....|..|.................|.....|..........
```

? To see, visualize, how such lists differ
(whether real, simulated or theoretical),
make a [QQ plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QQ_plot):
sort X, sort Y, plot the pairs (X<sub>j</sub>, Y<sub>j</sub>),
see how close that curve is to the line X = Y.
Also, [search QQ plot](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=qq+plot) here.

A [K-S test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-S_test)
gives a number from 0, X and Y identical,
to 1, way off; you could flip this around to 100 % down to 0 %.
However a QQ plot shows more directly where X and Y differ.

Comment: You're welcome Robert; could you post what you ended up using (in a week or so) ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like you need to formulate a question you want your data to answer. Let me suggest a few (perhaps you can edit your post to reflect what questions make sense for your data):

- As the DSMC value increases, does the theoretical result also increase?
- If I know the value of the theoretical result, how accurately can I estimate the value of DSMC?

If the points (1,x1) and (1,y1) refer to the same measurement or the same run of the experiment, or one is an estimate of the other. One natural way to see how related they are related is to plot {(x1,y1),(x2,y2) ...}.

You can read about Pearson correlation and Kendall tau and Spearman rho here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, those questions are not what I want to know. I updated the question, though.

Comment: +1 For a valiant attempt at deciphering the question and providing good advice.